# Syntax errors in ProtocolBuffers compiled swift 3

Tags: swift3, protocol-buffers

I am implementing ProtocolBuffers in Swift 3, and I followed the instructions on this page https://github.com/alexeyxo/protobuf-swift

It compiles successfully but the problem is that the syntax of the code is wrong for swift 3, my protocol version is -> libprotoc 2.6.1

This is an example of my .proto

```
message AptitudDto{
    optional int32 Id = 1;
    optional string Nombre = 2;
    optional string ImagenUrl = 3;
}
```

And i tried with this

```
syntax = "proto2";

message AptitudDto{
    optional int32 Id = 1;
    optional string Nombre = 2;
    optional string ImagenUrl = 3;
}
```

They all give me an errors in swift 3.

Comment: thanks! i change the libprotoc 2.6.1 to libprotoc 3.4.2 and this works

Answer (score 0):

You mention version 2.6.1, but there are more recent versions. If you're looking for support for Swift 3, consider upgrading.